# Getting music off an ipad into the computer

Tags: itunes, music, ipad

I just bought a new ipad, and need to move everything from the old one (an ipad 1) to the new one. I made a sync to the computer. Then made a restore to the new ipad. And then I found it did not copy over my music.
Some of those music files are not in my HD anymore. So if I lose it it might be gone for good. Is there any way in which I can get them out of the iPad in my HD memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) (for Mac), [PhoneDisk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/) (Windows or Mac), [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) (Windows and Mac, free, but you have to find where the music is)

Comment: Thanks, Phoneview made the trick. Phonedisk seemed ok until I realized that the data was given without any metadata.

Answer (score 1):

[SaveTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/savetunes-mp3-m4a-extractor/id400087368?mt=8) allows to extract audio files directly on the iDevice.